# Magento captcha not showing png file created

Tags: customer, customer-account, captcha

I've inherited this site from someone else. I had to install it into a sub-directory on a go daddy server.  Not sure where it came from. We have a customer registration form with a captcha that is not showing the .png file.  I have set the permissions to all folders that go to that file to 777.  When I view source code the path is correct and there is an image in that folder that was just created, but when I copy and paste the url path to the captcha image in the browser I receive a 500 internal server error.

Here's the form

http://wheybetterguard.com/wheybetterguard/shop/index.php/customer/account/create/

So I can see in the directory that the captcha image is created on page load example: http://wheybetterguard.com/wheybetterguard/shop/media/captcha/base/969f1d56057653feab9e8d392a11efd2.png

Everything seems to be working correctly except that the image is breaking for some reason.

Please help.

Comment: I get a 500 error page when opening the captcha URL

Comment: @RiccardoT That's what I'm trying to figure out.  There's an image there that I can download from the server and see the captcha code, but when it's on the site I can't visually see it through that URL, nor does the site.

Comment: I think it is a webserver issue, can you paste your server error.log?

Comment: Maybe a wrong URL rewrite

Comment: @RiccardoT I just started the error log.  Won't be available until March 1st.  Is there another way to get you that information?

Comment: Tell me more about your server configuration. If you have no critical data I would like to see your .htaccess

Comment: http://wheybetterguard.com/wheybetterguard/shop/htaccess.txt

@RiccardoT Had to make it a text file for viewing purposes.

Comment: Not sure, but try uncommenting the rewritebase at line 123.

Comment: Oh, I was forgetting... check if you have any .htaccess file inside /wheybetterguard/shop/media/captcha or inside /wheybetterguard/shop/media/captcha/base

Comment: Options All -Indexes
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_flag engine 0
</IfModule>

AddHandler cgi-script .php .pl .py .jsp .asp .htm .shtml .sh .cgi
Options -ExecCGI

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* ../get.php [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: That was in htaccess in media folder, but nothing in base or captcha

Comment: Yep, that is part of default Magento. Just for a test, could you temporary remove it to see if it fix the issue?

Comment: Server info http://wheybetterguard.com/wheybetterguard/shop/info.php

Comment: THAT DID IT!!!!

Is that okay. Do I need that file?

Comment: Yes and no, it is mainly used for DB images and to give a minumum protection. See my answer below with full details and please mark it as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but you may have some wrong htaccess directive inside

```
/wheybetterguard/shop/media/captcha/base
```

or inside

```
/wheybetterguard/shop/media/captcha
```

Try also by checking if you enabled the `RewriteBase` directive in you main `.htaccess` file.

I'm pretty sure it is an htaccess misconfiguration.

Also try temporarly removing the .htaccess file from `/wheybetterguard/shop/media`.

If it works you have some kind of issue with that htaccess file or with `get.php` file we should investigate on your `errors.log`.

That file is mainly used to permit the DB images and to give you a minumum discovery protection.

In case replace it with:

```
Options All -Indexes
```

It will give you a basic path discovery protection.

Comment: The problem was the /media/ .htaccess file. Further details will come from errors.log

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, this may work for others.

- Check Folder permission.
- Mine was set to "Root Root"
- I changed that to "www-data www-data"

And it worked fine for me.

[image: Captcha folder permission]